# Why is my request not routed?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I've created a simple WCF Service in an Application.
The "Server" is running on my maschine connected via LAN to my network.

It's IP is `192.168.56.1`.

Now when I try to connect from my mobile application to that Service it's not working.

The phone's ip is `192.168.0.17` and it's connected via WiFi.

Shouldn't my router just handle this for me and pass the request to the other subnet ?

If I set my computers IP to static (`192.168.0.88`) it's just working fine ...

Comment: How would the router know where to send the packet? And if the packet got to its destination, how would the destination machine know where to send the reply? Nothing happens by magic -- you have to configure this stuff.

Comment: So you have two different subnets on the same network segment? Maybe even with DHCP? That sounds like terrible network design.

Comment: True... thats what i thought.. Its just a default router i did not change anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192.168.56.X and 192.168.0.X are two different segments that cannot communicate without a bridge.

Ensure that the service IP is in the segment of 192.168.0.X if you want the router to broker the connection.